# TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments:

Tags: python, reactjs, tensorflow

I am trying to follow this tutorial [How to deploy your custom TensorFlow model to react native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pC7mCEHiYQw) to convert my model to be deployed to my reactjs webapp.

```
(Thesis) C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL>tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Desktop\Tan\Model\image-model\rabbit.h5 C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Desktop\Tan\Model\image-model\rabbit.h5
2022-11-18 15:30:20.943680: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-11-18 15:30:20.944067: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
usage: TensorFlow.js model converters. [-h]
                                       [--input_format {tf_frozen_model,tf_saved_model,tf_hub,tfjs_layers_model,keras_saved_model,keras}]
                                       [--output_format {tfjs_layers_model,keras_saved_model,keras,tfjs_graph_model}]
                                       [--signature_name SIGNATURE_NAME] [--saved_model_tags SAVED_MODEL_TAGS]
                                       [--quantize_float16 [QUANTIZE_FLOAT16]] [--quantize_uint8 [QUANTIZE_UINT8]]
                                       [--quantize_uint16 [QUANTIZE_UINT16]] [--quantization_bytes {1,2}]
                                       [--split_weights_by_layer] [--version] [--skip_op_check]
                                       [--strip_debug_ops STRIP_DEBUG_OPS]
                                       [--use_structured_outputs_names USE_STRUCTURED_OUTPUTS_NAMES]
                                       [--weight_shard_size_bytes WEIGHT_SHARD_SIZE_BYTES]
                                       [--output_node_names OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES] [--control_flow_v2 CONTROL_FLOW_V2]
                                       [--experiments EXPERIMENTS] [--metadata METADATA]
                                       [input_path] [output_path]
TensorFlow.js model converters.: error: unrecognized arguments: C:\Users\JHON MICHEAL\Desktop\Tan\Model\image-model\rabbit.h5
```

but I get this results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this argument is not correct

> --input_format=keras

and need to be changed to

> --input_format keras

you can see details here
https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras